# Customizing headings in git diff

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

When viewing a diff using `git diff`, each change starts with line like:

```
@@ -28,41 +20,10 @@ namespace ConsoleApplication1
```

For C, the final part is quite descriptive – it shows for example the function in which the change occurred. But for C#, it only ever shows the namespace, which isn't very useful. I think that's because it shows last line that isn't indented. Is there a way how to configure this?

Comment: did you manage to get a good configuration? I tried *.cs   diff=csharp, but I still get namespaces. diff=java works better though..

Comment: Yeah, it does work for me, do you have a recent enough version of git? diff=csharp should work since 1.7.3.

Comment: 1.7.10 here, from debian unstable, I'll try to dig later, for now java is ok :)

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111035/where-does-the-excerpt-in-the-git-diff-hunk-header-come-from

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have found it, the line is called hunk header and [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_generating_diff_text) says how to customize it:

> ### Defining a custom hunk-header
>
> Each group of changes (called a "hunk") in the textual diff output is prefixed with a line of the form:
>
> ```
> @@ -k,l +n,m @@ TEXT
> ```
>
> This is called a hunk header. The "TEXT" portion is by default a line that begins with an alphabet, an underscore or a dollar sign; this matches what GNU `diff -p` output uses. This default selection however is not suited for some contents, and you can use a customized pattern to make a selection.
>
> First, in .gitattributes, you would assign the `diff` attribute for paths.
>
> ```
> *.tex   diff=tex
> ```
>
> Then, you would define a "diff.tex.xfuncname" configuration to specify a regular expression that matches a line that you would want to appear as the hunk header "TEXT". Add a section to your `$GIT_DIR/config` file (or `$HOME/.gitconfig` file) like this:
>
> ```
> [diff "tex"]
>         xfuncname = "^(\\\\(sub)*section\\{.*)$"
> ```
>
> Note. A single level of backslashes are eaten by the configuration file parser, so you would need to double the backslashes; the pattern above picks a line that begins with a backslash, and zero or more occurrences of sub followed by section followed by open brace, to the end of line.

Answer (score 4):

See [gitattributes manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), the "Generating diff text" section, and e.g. `diff.csharp.xfuncname` configuration (search for `xfuncname`).