# Display Git diff on client side in javascript as html

Tags: javascript, git, diff, patch

So, in short, I'm basically looking for some info on:

1. a way to convert Git's diff format (that it gives you with the github api) into some kind of html format, like on the actual github website. If there's nothing like that,
2. I would like to have some information on the format of git's diff file, so I can write my own.

Comment: Is thre just no one who has any ideas?

Comment: As [Jaybeecave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1790331/jaybeecave) mentions below (ans I have edited the answer), you could consider https://diff2html.xyz/

Comment: I don't understand why some people like to use the [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) to shut down issues, rules are rigid, but people are flexible. Good matters should be encouraged more than shutting down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update 2017 (2 years later)

[Jaybeecave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790331/jaybeecave) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130861/display-git-diff-on-client-side-in-javascript-as-html/28131892#comment75230510_28131892) the tool [**diff2html.xyz**](https://diff2html.xyz/), a diff parser and pretty html generator.

---

The [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) format is inspired by the [diff -p](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) unix command.
(with -p being for `--show-c-function`: Show which C function each change is in.)

As I explain in "[Where does the excerpt in the `git diff` hunk header come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28111035/6309)", that feature ("Show which C function") has evolved to take into account other language.

This is similar to what you see in the `patch` field of the JSON answer [when you compare two commits with the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits).
That feature was [introduced in December 2012](https://developer.github.com/changes/2012-12-10-Diff-and-patch-media-types/)

> Simply use the same resource URL and send either `application/vnd.github.diff` or `application/vnd.github.patch` in the `Accept` header:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.diff" https://api.github.com/repos/pengwynn/dotfiles/commits/aee60a4cd56fb4c6a50e60f17096fc40c0d4d72c
```

Result:

```
diff --git a/tmux/tmux.conf.symlink b/tmux/tmux.conf.symlink
index 1f599cb..abaf625 100755
--- a/tmux/tmux.conf.symlink
+++ b/tmux/tmux.conf.symlink
@@ -111,6 +111,7 @@ set-option -g base-index 1
 ## enable mouse
 set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
 set-option -g mouse-select-window on
+set-option -g mouse-resize-pane on
 set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
 set-window-option -g mode-mouse on
 # set-window-option -g monitor-activity off
```

The format follows the classic **[`diff` unified format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format)** (also [detailed here](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified)).
You can see an example in [`cubicdaiya/node-dtl`](https://github.com/cubicdaiya/node-dtl) (an dtl(diff template library) binding for node.js)

Comment: Yes, but what is the format, and is there a way to convert it to HTML in client side JS?

Comment: @ChristopherDumas not sure about the html part, but I have added the format in the (now edited) answer.

Comment: https://diff2html.xyz/ is what you want

Comment: @Jaybeecave Nice! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.