# Git: Diff a list of functions

Tags: git

I am trying to get the names of the functions that contains changes via "git diff " command. Is there a simple way to do it?

I want to make a report that shows which functions were changed.
I tried "--name-only" flag, but it only gives changed files, and I need changed functions.

Output:
show_time($$)
show_date($$)

Comment: You can filter the output from the git diff with some shell  commands. Git itself doesn't recognise functions, each language has different syntax, git is not "trained" on a language, but there might be packages that can enhance such functionality for git.

Comment: Git does not care enough for the inner structure of the source code to get this information out in a direct way. The underlying diff command puts function names sometimes into the hunk line indicators (lines starting with @@), but it fails to find every reference, and also happily continue with the diff even if other function names are found along the way.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in "[Where does the excerpt in the git diff hunk header come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111535/6309)", a diff hunk can include the name of the function.

You could grep this [hunk header](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header) in order to get the list of functions, provided the file is in one of the supported languages.
(Or you would need to [customize the diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_customizing_word_diff))