# What's the text after the second @@ in git diff

Tags: git

When I check out for example the git repository `https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch.git` (taken at random from github) and then do

```
git diff eaee02ffdf5d820729ccdf2f95fa08b08c7d24d2^ eaee02ffdf5d820729ccdf2f95fa08b08c7d24d2
```

to view a commit, I get something starting with

```
diff --git a/crates/core_arch/src/core_arch_docs.md b/crates/core_arch/src/core_arch_docs.md
index 58b7eda9..eddd1fc0 100644
--- a/crates/core_arch/src/core_arch_docs.md
+++ b/crates/core_arch/src/core_arch_docs.md
@@ -194,18 +194,18 @@ others at:
 * [`nvptx`]
 * [`wasm32`]
 
-[`x86`]: x86/index.html
-[`x86_64`]: x86_64/index.html
-[`arm`]: arm/index.html
-[`aarch64`]: aarch64/index.html
-[`riscv32`]: riscv32/index.html
-[`riscv64`]: riscv64/index.html
-[`mips`]: mips/index.html
-[`mips64`]: mips64/index.html
-[`powerpc`]: powerpc/index.html
-[`powerpc64`]: powerpc64/index.html
-[`nvptx`]: nvptx/index.html
-[`wasm32`]: wasm32/index.html
+[`x86`]: ../../core/arch/x86/index.html
+[`x86_64`]: ../../core/arch/x86_64/index.html
+[`arm`]: ../../core/arch/arm/index.html
+[`aarch64`]: ../../core/arch/aarch64/index.html
```

I'm wondering about the text after the second `@@` in the fifth line (in this case `others at:`). From other examples I had the impression that most of the time it's the line immediately preceding the quoted text block, but in this specific case, looking at [the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rust-lang/stdarch/master/crates/core_arch/src/core_arch_docs.md) shows us that it's not the line immediately preceding the block, in fact 14 lines further up.

What's the point of the text after the `@@` in general? Is it maybe to have something easily fulltext-searchable in a large file? Is it maybe documented somewhere?

Comment: I think it's specific to whatever program `git diff` uses to generate the diff. `git help diff` only documents what the *number* of `@` bracketing the chunk header means; it doesn't say anything about text following it.

Comment: "*The optional header shows the C function where each change occurs, if it is a C file, … or the equivalent, if any, for other types of files.*"

Comment: @phd thanks for your answer. I wouldn't have minded some more details if the question hadn't been closed ...

Comment: There *is* documentation for how to tell Git how to create the text-after-@@. It is buried in [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes); search for "custom hunk-header".

Comment: Thanks @torek! Now that I know that it's called "hunk header", it's easier to google for [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111035/where-does-the-excerpt-in-the-git-diff-hunk-header-come-from)

Comment: I still think this should be reopened. The cited question is more general and doesn't ask my specific issue, and the top answer doesn't address it either. Only a later answer has a side remark giving a hint. I'm sure more people are wondering about the same thing, and having an easily googleable explanation would help